# Differentiability of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a vector field in $S^2$ that is $(ax_1+bx_2) \frac \partial {\partial x_1}+(cx_1+dx_2) \frac \partial {\partial x_2}$ on every point on the sphere except the north pole and $0$ on the north pole. $φ=(x_1,x_2)$ is the chart with formula
$φ(x,y,z)=( \frac x{1-z}, \frac y{1-z})$.

I need to find $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R$ so that $X$ is differentiable.

By changing coordinates from $(x_1,x_2)$ to $(y_1,y_2)= ( \frac x{1+z}, \frac y{1+z})$, it is easy to see that for $a=d$ and $b=-c$, $X$ is differentiable in (0,0,1) (the north pole).

My question is if these are the only solutions?

Comment: Differentiability is a local question, your vector field is clearly differentiable on any point in the chart you have given. The only point not in the chart is the north pole. Evaluate the form of the vector field in a chart around the north pole to find conditions on $a,b, c, d$ so that the field remains differentiable there.

Comment: Yes that's what I've done. I found some conditions. What I can't do is see if there are more. Are there?